# SQL Server 2012: Update table with inner join after sorted

Tags: performance, sql-server-2012, sql-update, inner-join

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a table called `table1` like below:

```
Id col1 col2 col3 Name
1   a    b   abc  null
2   b    c   mno  null
```

And I have another table `table2`, like below:

```
Id col1 col2 col3 Name
1  %    %    abc  Name1
2  a    %    abc  Name2
3  %    b    abc  Name3
4  a    b    abc  Name4
```

I have to update `Name` column in `Table1` From `Name` column in `Table2` based on columns: `col1`, `col2` and `col3`.
The `Id = 1` in the `table1` finds all 4 matches in the table because I am using like operator in `col1` and `col2` to compare(why I am using like is if it didn't find exact match it should accept `%` as a match).
Now my problem is if exact match is there for the columns `col1`, `col2` and `col3` in the table, it should consider that only not the rows with '`%`' value. For example, for the `Id=1` in the `table1`, the result should be from `id=4` in the `table2`.
I tried with following query:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET name = t2.Name
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 
        t1.id, t2.name 
      FROM table1 t1 
        INNER JOIN table2 t2 
        ON t1.col3 = t2.col3 AND t1.col1 LIKE t2.col1 
                             AND t1.col2 LIKE t2.col2 
      ORDER BY t2.col1, t2.col2) AS t3
WHERE id = t3.id;
```

But I am not getting result which I expected. And also, there are 8,000,000 records are there in `table1` so it should not affect performance.
Please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At a first try, I suggest this:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET name = t2.Name
FROM (SELECT TOP(1) *
      FROM (SELECT
                t1.id, t2.name, t2.col1, t2.col2, 2 As ord
            FROM table1 t1 
              INNER JOIN table2 t2 
                 ON t1.col3 = t2.col3 AND t1.col1 LIKE t2.col1 
                                      AND t1.col2 LIKE t2.col2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                t1.id, t2.name, t2.col1, t2.col2, 1 As ord
            FROM table1 t1 
              INNER JOIN table2 t2 
                 ON t1.col3 = t2.col3 AND t1.col1 = t2.col1 
                                      AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
            ) DT
      ORDER BY ord, col1, col2) AS t3
WHERE id = t3.id;
```

Comment: @sanmathi Performance will be less than the original query, but I use `UNION ALL` to maker lower effects ;).

Comment: I will check and let you know how it is working in my machine. Thanks for the help.